# Magic committer not improving performance in a Spark3+Yarn3+S3 setup

Tags: performance, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, pyspark

### What I am trying to achieve?

I am trying to enable the [S3A magic committer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html) for my Spark3.3.0 application running on a Yarn (Hadoop 3.3.1) cluster, to see performance improvements in my app during S3 writes. IIUC, my Spark application is writing about 21GBs of data with 30 tasks in the corresponding Spark stage (see below image).

[image: Spark app's stages UI]

### My setup

I have a server which has the Spark client. The Spark client submits the application on Yarn cluster via the client-mode with PySpark.

### What I tried

I am using the following config (setting via PySpark Spark-conf) to enable the committer:

```
"spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass": "org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol"
"spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class": "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.BindingPathOutputCommitter"
"spark.hadoop.mapreduce.outputcommitter.factory.scheme.s3a": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.S3ACommitterFactory"
"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name": "magic"
"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.magic.enabled": "true"
```

I also downloaded the [spark-hadoop-cloud](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12/3.3.1) jar to the `jars/` directory of the Spark-Home on the Nodemanagers and my Spark-client servers.

##### Changes that I see after applying the aforementioned configs:

1. I see `PRE __magic/` directory if I run `aws s3 ls <write-path>` when the job is running.
2. I don't see the warning `WARN AbstractS3ACommitterFactory: Using standard FileOutputCommitter to commit work. This is slow and potentially unsafe.` anymore.
3. A `_SUCCESS` file gets created with (JSON) content. One of the key-value that I see in that file is `"committer" : "magic"`.

Hence, I believe my configs are getting applied correctly.

### What I expect

I have read in multiple articles that this committer is expected to show a performance boost (e.g. [this article](https://medium.com/insiderengineering/spark-3-reduced-our-emr-cost-by-40-144f17987af5) claims 57-77% time reduction). Hence, I expect to see significant reduction (from 39s) in the "duration" column of my "paruqet" stage, when I use the above shared configs.

### Some other point that might be of value

1. When I use `"spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass": "com.hortonworks.spark.cloud.commit.PathOutputCommitProtocol"`, my app fails with the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hortonworks.spark.cloud.commit.PathOutputCommitProtocol`.
2. I have not looked into enabling S3gaurd, as [S3 now provides strong consistency](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/consistency/).

Comment: Your stage #0 reads 23MB in 15 seconds, which I wouldn't call fast either. If it happens to read from the same S3, maybe the problem is not in slow commit?

Comment: Hey @mazaneicha! Thanks for chimming in and that is a good observation. My input is coming via an SQL query, so it might be logic of the SQL which is taking that much time. I will check further on this.

But, if I understand correctly, you're suggesting something possibly slow with the network between my EC2 box & S3?

Comment: Hmmm... stage 0 looks like a very straightforward select-count (at least there is no evidence of any complex SQL processing on your screenshot). So yes, I'd feel a bit suspicious about EC2-S3 link. Your committer algo concerns -- we're lucky to have @stevel expertly cover them in his answer! :))

Comment: Here is a code snippet of how I am running this benchmark. I run [this code](https://gist.github.com/akki/c2c817c71ae04ee654bb97b26595fb7b) & then look at the Spark UI ("stages" tab) for the time taken by the "parquet at NativeMethodAccessorImpl" stage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. correct. you don't need s3guard
2. the com.hortonworks binding was for the wip committer work. the binding classes for wiring up spark/parquet are all in spark-hadoop-cloud and have org.spark prefixes. you seem to be ok there
3. the simple test for what committer is live is to print the JSON _SUCCESS file. If that is a 0 byte file, you are still using the old committer. it does sound like you are.

grab the latest spark+hadoop build you can get, there's always ongoing improvements, with hadoop 3.3.5 doing a big enhancement there.

you should see performance improvements compared to the v1 committer, with commit speed O(files) rather than O(data). it is also *correct*, which the v1 algorithm doesn't offer on s3 (and which v2 doesn't offer *anywhere*

Comment: Hi, I appreciate you writing this answer. The most important learning here for me seems "simple test for what committer is live is to print the JSON _SUCCESS file". I don't currently see any _SUCCESS file in the S3 directory I am writing to - maybe that is because I am writing to parquet (with `session.write.parquet()`) - I'll try to write my data in JSON & see if I can see the _SUCCESS file. Thanks again for sharing this answer.

Comment: marker should go in through parquet, even on the original committers, if spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs is true. different for dynamic partitioning, but that doesn't work properly on s3

Comment: Thanks @stevel for pointing that out. Sorry for the delay but I am finally able to produce the _SUCCESS file now. In my case, it contains a JSON (it's a 302 lines file) and it has `"committer" : "magic"` in it. Is there anything else I should be looking here? (I also confirmed that without my magic-committer configs, the _SUCCESS file is zero bytes)

Comment: In case it adds any value, I added the code snippet I am using for this benchmark [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74753780/magic-committer-not-improving-performance-in-a-spark3yarn3s3-setup#comment132248839_74753780).

Comment: if you can , grab the hadoop 3.3.5 RC up on the apache site and play with that...lots of improvement of the magic committer perf/scale, especially on parquet files.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try out the newer version of Hadoop.

Comment: I tried finding Spark built with Hadoop3.3.4 (from Spark's [downloads](shorturl.at/oSUV1)) but it still seems shipped with Hadoop3.3.1. I'll wait for Spark to be released with newer Hadoop (or maybe find some time to build Spark). ~=~ Meanwhile, I did try benchmarking by writing my data in CSV (instead of parquet) and still see no performance improvements. Are any of the bug fixes in recent Hadoop related to all (or CSV?) formats? Or is this enough proof to believe that upgrading Hadoop won't help in my case? ~=~ I want to thank you again for looking so keenly into my case.